# no aar file generated after building spotify wrapper with gradle

Tags: android, api, gradle, spotify, aar

I'm trying to start developing the spotify streamer app from a course in udacity. But i'm having trouble while following these steps:

```
This project is built using Gradle:
Clone the repository: git clone https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android.git
Build: ./gradlew assemble
Grab the aar that can be found in build/outputs/aar/spotify-web-api-android-0.1.0.aar and put it in the libs folder in your application
```

Everything worked except the last step. The process didnt create a build/outputs/aar directory. All I see are 3 folders inside my app\build directory:

> apk
>
> lint-results-release-fatal_files
>
> logs

and thats it. The steps are from :

> https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I was running the ".\gradlew assemble" command from my application folder. Running the same command from the cloned git folder ('spotify-web-api-android') created the .aar file successfully

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with this as well. If you have the spotify web api in your android directory and building the file doesn't generate the aar file, simply copy your local.properties file   from the root of your android projects directory that will supply the SDK location. Failure to do this and running the above command from the web api directory will result in git trying to redownload the SDK just to compile that file